# What's wrong?, I want to copy the image file to my other directory after upload, and input it to the mysql database too

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-upload

this is my code

```
<?php
    include 'koneksi.php';

    $judul_artikel = $_POST['judul_artikel'];
    $isi_artikel = $_POST['isi_artikel'];
    $tanggal_artikel = date('Y-m-d');
    $tag_artikel = $_POST['tag_artikel'];

    $filetmp = $_FILES["gambar_artikel"]["tmp_name"];
    $filename = $_FILES["gambar_artikel"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["gambar_artikel"]["type"];
    $filepath = "img/".$filename;

    move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);
    
    $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO artikel(judul_artikel,isi_artikel,tanggal_artikel,tag_artikel,gambar_artikel) VALUES ("'.$judul_artikel.'","'.$isi_artikel.'","'.$tanggal_artikel.'","'.$tag_artikel.'","'.$filepath.'")')or die(mysql_error());

    if ($query) {
        header('location:artikel.php?notif=berhasil');
    } else {
        header('location:artikel.php?notif=gagal');
    }
?>
```

the problem I face is, I want to copy the image file to another directory after I upload it, and input it into the mysql database too, but when I execute, the file that I upload is not copied in the directory that I want, and is not inputted into the mysql database, how to handle it ?

Comment: which version of PHP you used???

Comment: and `$_POST[]` data is inserted or not???

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injection - use a `prepared statement` instead of embedding variables in the SQL. As for saving the file, try `$filepath = __DIR__ . "/img/".$filename;` as the $filepath

Comment: You should not be using the `mysql` api it was deprecated years ago and removed from PHP7+ - as already asked, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: As mentioned, please stop using this ancient, insecure, and deprecated API.

Comment: I use php5, but in other actions, it runs smoothly, but not in this action, so how do I overcome this? or maybe I need to change the entire code?

Comment: adding '__DIR__' not help :( still failed

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap it inside if condition like this

```
if(move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath)){
  echo "success";
}else{
  echo "failed";
}
```

and make sure you set the folder permission

Comment: what about the folder permission?